# Will a sorted List<string> perform a contains faster

Tags: .net, sorting

If I perform a Contains() on a list of sorted simple string tags (as opposed to complex sentences), will it run any faster than a randomly sorted one? If not, what is a better data structure. I don't necessarily want to hash them first in a dictionary ( for performance reasons), but I'm open to suggestions

Comment: Well, it will be faster for the Strings that end up near the head of the list. And if the list knows that it is sorted, it could do a binary search (but I guess it does not know that).

Comment: Why not just use `List<T>.BinarySearch`?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Not if you just sort `List<string>`, no. You could use [`List<T>.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839.aspx), but `Contains` won't do it for you as it doesn't really "know" that your list is sorted. Hashing them is precisely *for* performance though - [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) is likely to be your best bet - it will have O(1) `Contains` performance assuming you don't run into hash collisions.

You could use [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) in .NET 4 which is basically a sorted list - you'll get O(log n) performance, but that won't require a hash computation, which *could* speed things up if your strings are extremely long. (You'd need to benchmark to be sure, of course.) This is broadly equivalent to the "sort and then use binary search" approach, but doesn't rely on you doing things manually.

`SortedList<,>` and `SortedDictionary<,>` are also available if you're only using .NET 2, but ideally you should use a set if you don't need a key/value mapping and you don't care about order.

Comment: If the list knows that it is sorted, it could do a binary search.

Comment: @Thilo: But the list doesn't keep that information. The OP could call BinarySearch themselves though - I edited that in just now.

Comment: @JaredPar: Eek - will edit that. How strange... I thought it was available before then.

Comment: @Jon, I'm losing it. I was reading the MSDN page wrong.  It's been around since 2.0

Comment: @JaredPar: Hang on - I've just double-checked the docs, and it's available from .NET 2.0. Which version were you looking at?

Comment: @Jon It's my bad.  I was looking at the top of the page (current version) and not the bottom (supported versions). :(

Comment: @JaredPar: Yes, it's a bit confusing in that respect. It would arguably be more useful to have that information right at the top - although there's only so much you can put above the fold.

Comment: Thanks Jon/Jared, I can't believe BinarySearch has escaped my attention all these years :/